# In addition to $K_e/K_m = c^2$ (due to James Clerk Maxwell), are the constants that arise from $G/K_m$ and $G/K_e$ also limits?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, units, dimensional-analysis

Prior to James Clerk Maxwell we understood there to be three laws:

$$\text{Gravity: }\;\;\; F_g= G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
$$\text{Electricity: } F_e= K_e \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
$$\text{Magnetism:  } F_m= K_m \frac{p_1p_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

Maxwell found that the speed of light, c, can be deribed by $c=\sqrt{\frac{K_e}{K_m}}$. In doing so, combining two laws that prior to him were thought to have nothing in common. Following this idea, of dividing constants in these three laws, we have two more such constants:

$$\sqrt{\frac{K_e}{K_m}}= 3.0  \times 10^{8} \frac{m}{s}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{G}{K_e}} = 8.62 \times 10^{-11} \frac{C}{Kg}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{G}{K_m}} = 2.59 \times 10^{9} \frac{m \cdot C}{s \cdot Kg}$$

My question is, are these other two "constants" used in physics for anything? In particular, the Coulombs per Kilogram constant...how is that even interpreted?

Comment: There is no such magnetic force law, because there are no magnetic monopoles (at least, not in Maxwell electromagnetism).  The magnetic force between dipoles is a $1/r^3$ law, and it is not as simple as you've written there because the relative positions and orientations of the dipoles matter.

Comment: Caltech lectures on that charge (though I am sure it does not matter): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRzqL9BAeYA

Comment: @ReverseFlow The law you put there for magnetism was not prior to Maxwell because Gauss (before Maxwell) showed mathematically that  "net magnetic charges" (magnetic monopoles) didn't exist, and so mathematically there was no such magnetic law as you put there then (at least not until Dirac's time).